# Where to find are all the Prismatic (getprismatic.com) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, news-feed

Found really nice automatic news agregator service http://getprismatic.com. I’m a keyboard centric user, and there are shortcuts on Prismatic website like greader’s <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> for next/previous and etc. But what are all the shortcuts? Can you show where is the list of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have just started to implement them.

> One of the goals we’re shooting for is to be able to use the entire web app without a mouse at all. We’re not quite there yet, but there are many shortcuts currently available:

- <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>: Jump to next/previous article
- <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>: Scroll to next/previous article with animation
- <kbd>space</kbd>: Scroll to next article
- <kbd>s</kbd>: open share box for active article
- <kbd>o</kbd>: open active article in new tab
- <kbd>b</kbd>: bookmark active article in new tab
- <kbd>f</kbd>: Go to search field and find new interests.

[Source](http://prismaticblog.dreamhosters.com/?p=3).

Comment: Thank you..Bad they dont have shortcut to interested/not interested functions.

Comment: @0x49D1 just yet. I believe they will get there in the future.